# Fetch all nested data from firebase firestore to react native [expo] app

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am new for react native and firebase So please help me I am struggling with this for almost 2-3 days. I have structured my data in firestore like given below .Now I want to fetch data to my react native expo app while mapping main data I am not getting any error but while mapping nested data I am getting error "undefined is not a function"

[image: Fireatore Data]

[image: This is how I fetch data in my app]

[image: But when I want to fetch my nested map block]

Please help me I am struggling to fetch all nested data.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nestedBlock is an object so you cannot use map directly, if you want to loop through it, you can iterate its keys using map like follow:

```
{Object.keys(i.nestedBlock).map((n) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{i.nestedBlock[n]}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  })}
```